# Flutter RangeSlider - labels always displayed above track bar

Tags: flutter, slider, flutter-layout

I'm using a `RangeSlider` widget, instead of displaying the selected values when sliding I would like to have my main divisions values displayed above the track bar. Currently the only solution I came up with is puting a `Row` of `Text` widgets above my slider but the values and labels are not properly aligned.

**My code**

```dart
final _sliderLabels = <String>[
    'Bac',
    'Bac +2',
    'Bac +3',
    'Bac +4',
    'Bac +5',
    '>Bac +5'
  ];

Widget _buildSlider() {
    return Column(
      children: [
        _buildLabel("Niveaux d'études"),
        SizedBox(height: 10),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            ..._sliderLabels.map((e) => Text(e)),
          ],
        ),
        SliderTheme(
          data: SliderThemeData(
            showValueIndicator: ShowValueIndicator.never,
            thumbColor: Colors.blue,
            trackHeight: 2,
            activeTrackColor: Colors.blue,
            inactiveTrackColor: Colors.grey,
          ),
          child: StreamBuilder<RangeValues>(
            stream: _onSliderValuesChanged,
            builder: (_, snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) return Container();
              return RangeSlider(
                onChanged: (value) => _sliderValuesController.sink.add(value),
                min: 0,
                max: _sliderLabels.length.toDouble(),
                divisions: _sliderLabels.length,
                values: snapshot.data,
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

**Picture**
[image]

As you can see the label `Bac +5` is not aligned with my thumb.

Do you have any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

**For anyone that is looking for a way to always show labels.** I created (in my opinion) a generic range slider widget when I was trying to do the same thing. There are defaults for all the inputs, so It will "run out of the box." If you don't want labels, then pass an empty container to both the labels. If you want a star or a square for one of the sliders, Then you have the freedom to do so.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

/// a range slider that fits the box it is given.
/// colors can be customized. Also, if thumbSlider,
/// leftLabel, or rightLabel is given, there is
/// greater option for customizability.
class CustomRangeSlider extends StatefulWidget {
  //expect "lowerValue" and "upperValue" as keys
  final Function(RangeSliderValues) onChange;
  final int min;
  final int max;
  final int lowerValue; // lower value that is selected.
  final int upperValue; // higher number that is selected
  final int barHeight; // height of the containers between thumb sliders
  final Color selectedColor;
  final Color deselectedColor;
  final Widget? leftThumbSlider; //by default, it is a blue circle.
  final Widget? rightThumbSlider; //by default, it is a blue circle.
  final Widget? leftLabel; //by default, it is blue text
  final Widget? rightLabel; //by default, it is blue text

  const CustomRangeSlider(
      {Key? key,
      required this.onChange,
      this.max = 10,
      this.min = 0,
      this.lowerValue = 0,
      this.upperValue = 10,
      this.barHeight = 2,
      this.selectedColor = Colors.blue,
      this.deselectedColor = Colors.grey,
      this.leftThumbSlider,
      this.rightThumbSlider,
      this.leftLabel,
      this.rightLabel})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CustomRangeSliderState createState() => _CustomRangeSliderState();
}

class _CustomRangeSliderState extends State<CustomRangeSlider> {
  late int lowerValue = 0;
  late int upperValue = 0;
  late Widget leftThumbSlider;
  late Widget rightThumbSlider;
  late Widget leftLabel;
  late Widget rightLabel;
  int? dragStartVal;

  @override
  void initState() {
    if (widget.leftThumbSlider != null) {
      leftThumbSlider = widget.leftThumbSlider!;
    } else {
      leftThumbSlider = getDefaultThumbSlider(key: Key("leftThumbSlider"));
    }
    if (widget.rightThumbSlider != null) {
      rightThumbSlider = widget.rightThumbSlider!;
    } else {
      rightThumbSlider = getDefaultThumbSlider(key: Key("rightThumbSlider"));
    }
    if (widget.leftLabel != null) {
      leftLabel = widget.leftLabel!;
    } else {
      leftLabel = getDefaultLabel();
    }
    if (widget.rightLabel != null) {
      rightLabel = widget.rightLabel!;
    } else {
      rightLabel = getDefaultLabel(isLeft: false);
    }
    lowerValue = widget.lowerValue;
    upperValue = widget.upperValue;
    super.initState();
  }

  Widget getDefaultThumbSlider({Key? key}) {
    return Container(
      key: key,
      height: 25,
      width: 25,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: widget.selectedColor,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
          Radius.circular(50),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void onChange() {
    widget.onChange(
        RangeSliderValues(lowerValue: lowerValue, upperValue: upperValue));
  }

  Widget getDefaultLabel({bool isLeft = true}) {
    return Container(
      width: 25,
      child: Center(
        child: Text(
          isLeft ? "$lowerValue" : "$upperValue",
          style: TextStyle(
              color: widget.selectedColor,
              fontSize: 11,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
      return Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
            children: [
              Expanded(
                flex: lowerValue - widget.min,
                child: Container(),
              ),
              getDefaultLabel(),
              Expanded(
                flex: upperValue - lowerValue,
                child: Container(),
              ),
              getDefaultLabel(isLeft: false),
              Expanded(
                flex: widget.max - upperValue,
                child: Container(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 2,
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                flex: lowerValue - widget.min,
                child: Container(
                  height: widget.barHeight * 1,
                  color: widget.deselectedColor,
                ),
              ),
              Column(
                children: [
                  GestureDetector(
                    onHorizontalDragStart: (DragStartDetails details) {
                      dragStartVal = lowerValue;
                    },
                    onHorizontalDragEnd: (DragEndDetails details) {
                      dragStartVal = null;
                    },
                    onHorizontalDragUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails details) {
                      double totalDistanceTraveled = details.localPosition.dx;
                      double distanceBetweenValues =
                          constraints.maxWidth / (widget.max - widget.min);
                      int numSteps =
                          (totalDistanceTraveled / distanceBetweenValues)
                              .round();
                      int beforeChange = lowerValue;
                      if (dragStartVal != null) {
                        setState(() {
                          lowerValue = dragStartVal! + numSteps;
                          if (lowerValue < widget.min) lowerValue = widget.min;
                          if (lowerValue >= upperValue) {
                            lowerValue = upperValue - 1;
                          }
                        });
                        if (beforeChange != lowerValue) onChange();
                      }
                    },
                    child: leftThumbSlider,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: upperValue - lowerValue,
                child: Container(
                  height: widget.barHeight * 1,
                  color: widget.selectedColor,
                ),
              ),
              Column(
                children: [
                  GestureDetector(
                    onHorizontalDragStart: (DragStartDetails details) {
                      dragStartVal = upperValue;
                    },
                    onHorizontalDragEnd: (DragEndDetails details) {
                      dragStartVal = null;
                    },
                    onHorizontalDragUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails details) {
                      double totalDistanceTraveled = details.localPosition.dx;
                      double distanceBetweenValues =
                          constraints.maxWidth / (widget.max - widget.min);
                      int numSteps =
                          (totalDistanceTraveled / distanceBetweenValues)
                              .round();
                      int beforeChange = upperValue;
                      if (dragStartVal != null) {
                        setState(() {
                          upperValue = dragStartVal! + numSteps;
                          if (upperValue > widget.max) upperValue = widget.max;
                          if (upperValue <= lowerValue) {
                            upperValue = lowerValue + 1;
                          }
                        });
                        if (beforeChange != upperValue) onChange();
                      }
                    },
                    child: rightThumbSlider,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: widget.max - upperValue,
                child: Container(
                  height: widget.barHeight * 1,
                  color: widget.deselectedColor,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      );
    });
  }
}

class RangeSliderValues {
  int lowerValue;
  int upperValue;
  RangeSliderValues({required this.lowerValue, required this.upperValue});
}
```

Comment: I like your approach, but labels don't work from this snippet, so I needed to fix it. But anyway, thank you - its very helpful.

Comment: @rgolovakha, Feel free to suggest an edit with your fix.

Comment: You are assigning labels at lines 66, 71, but according to 124 and 129 are not using it. Even so - I was not able to make it working this way. But actually my need was covered just by providing TextStyle arg for both labels. To extend this option I think it can work if pass the "parent" for your labels (padding, borders, etc) - but I did not check it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween`

Comment: It is a bit better but still not aligned perfectly.

Comment: That's likely because your text is too long relative to the size of the "dot" on the slider. Would it be ok to remove the "Bac" prefix and just keep the "+2", "+3", etc?

Comment: Yeah I thought about that too but unfortunately I cannot reduce the label...

Comment: Then perhaps you could consider using another control (e.g. a pair of dropdowns)